# Adicionar uma vogal por vez em uma TextView

Tags: java, android

Tenho 5 botões que emulam vogais, como faz cada botão adicionar uma vogal por vez a um visor, definido como `TextView` ?

Comment: A cada vez que apertar a tecla, por exemplo botão "A", você concatena o conteúdo da textview + "A", e será a textview novamente. Lembrando que, se o textview estiver vazio, pode dar crash, então verifica antes com o length.

Comment: "será" = "seta"

Answer (score 2):

1. Coloque em tela os 5 botões e um TexTView.
2. Implemente a classe View.OnClickListener.
3. Defina o evento dessa classe para cada botão.
4. No disparo do evento, utilize um comando switch para manipular os botões.

   - Com uma string "Texto" auxiliar, as vogais são concatenadas. Ao final do evento o TextView é definido.

---

```
private Button btnA, btnE, btnI, btnO, btnU;
private TextView textView;
private String Texto="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);

    btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA);
    btnE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnE);
    btnI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnI);
    btnO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnO);
    btnU = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnU);

    btnA.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnE.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnI.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnO.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnU.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnA:
            Texto += "A";
        break;
        case R.id.btnE:
            Texto += "E";
            break;
        case R.id.btnI:
            Texto += "I";
            break;
        case R.id.btnO:
            Texto += "O";
            break;
        case R.id.btnU:
            Texto += "U";
            break;
    }
    textView.setText(Texto);
}
```

> Esse é o jeito que eu faria, atualmente. Há outras formas de realizar isso.

- Imagem da tela: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN1wz.jpg